# Tkinter OptionMenu, How to call diffrent func on each option

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

am doing a GUI which includes option menu I have defined the following menu to take the options from a list, however I would like to make the each option call a different function, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
    options = ["Modem ID: 20",
                "Modem ID: 30",
                "Modem ID: 40", 
                "Modem ID: 50"]

    selected_Option
    selected_Option = tk.StringVar(self) 
    selected_Option.set(options[0])
    drop_Menu =apply(OptionMenu, (self, selected_Option) + tuple(options))
    drop_Menu.place(relx=.809, y=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.trace(..)` function on `StringVar` to monitor the change of the value, and then do whatever you want based on the selected option:

```
def onOptionChanged(*args):
    modem_id = int(selected_Option.get().split(':')[1])
    if modem_id == 10:
        # do something
    elif modem_id == 20:
        # do other stuff
    ...

...
selected_Option = StringVar()
selected_Option.trace('w', onOptionChanged)
...
```